What set do these four bags of LEGO pieces belong to?
Which set do these bags of LEGO pieces belong to?
Can anyone help identify them?


This question is similar to: How can I identify a set based on one or more original sealed bags?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

These are certainly not from one set - as it turns out, they are four bags from at least five different sets.
The upper left bag is from 70146 Flying Phoenix Fire Temple, based on these parts.
The upper right bag is from 80011 Red Son's Inferno Truck, based on these parts.
The lower left bag is from 41179 Queen Dragon's Rescue, based on these parts.
The lower right bag is a mix with parts from 70612 Green Ninja Mech Dragon, based on the Master Wu minifigure and the sand green Hero Factory Foot. It seems to be taped together because there is also 49193 (Minifigure Cape Cloth, Dementor Style)
